# Instantiate a "grok view" with the parameters self.context and self.request in another grok view

Tags: plone, grok

I have a site product with a code like this:

```
class AClass(grok.View):
    """ Code of AClass """
    pass

class BClass(AClass):
    """ Code of BClass with 'update' method defined """
    pass

class CClass(BClass):
    def update(self):
        self.panel = BClass(self.context, self.request)
        # more code
```

My doubt is why `BClass` is instantiate/called in `CClass` code with two parameters (`self.context` and `self.request`). 
`BClass` has a update method without other parameters (just `self`) and doesn't have a `__init__` method explicitly.
So, what's the function of `self.context` and `self.request` in this case? Is this a kind of inheritance or acquisition?

After that I saw this, I think so that I didn't fully understand the omnipresent concepts of context and container in Plone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense to both subclass from BClass and have a BClass as an instance. I don't understand what the line `self.panel = BClass(self.context, self.request)` is supposed to achieve.

context and container are in no way omnipresent.  The context is the object which you are viewing. It is set in the classes `__init__` method. The container is an attribute of the context, typically `__parent__`.

Comment: Thanks, @Lennart Regebro! I was never instantiate a grok View with parameters before. I took a look at the grok Documentation (http://grok.zope.org/doc/1.5/reference/components.html#grok.View) and saw that `grok.View` really accepts `self.context` and `self.request` as 'constructor' parameters. Normally I always instantiate a `grok.View` without parameters and never worked with this case of instantiate a view inside another. Is this a good pattern?
Thanks so much and sorry for my unclear question.

Comment: @LeonardoAndrade: It is very rare that you need to instantiate views at all. My guess is that whenever you instantiate a view you are doing something wrong. Views are instantiated on objects by the publisher.